# Jenkins pipeline is unable to terminate a docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a docker container that performs some tasks and is scheduled inside Jenkins pipeline like this:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('1') {
            steps {
                sh "docker run -i --rm test"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the pipeline is aborted somehow, by timeout or manually for example, the container won't stop and stays alive.

How do I configure it to be terminated along with pipeline?

`Docker version 17.06-ce`

Comment: Stop container before providing another test.

Comment: And another important question here. Why do you need to manual stop or it sometimes timeout.

Comment: It hangs sometimes or our blocking something important, so I want to be able to terminate job whenever I want.
Right now I cat terminate it but the most resource consuming part (the container) wouldn't be affected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Elessar you can configure an "always" in the post steps. Mainly it will run the command inside always without depending on the build cancelation, fail or success.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                 sh "docker run -i --rm test"
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            sh "docker stop test" //or something similar 
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this solve your problem!

Comment: Yeah I know it but in real case I have 3 containers running one after another and the logic of such termination would be rather messy

Comment: I have check the docker documentation and you can also set the --stop-timeout flag ( API 1.25+)--> Timeout (in seconds) to stop a container. I dont know if that is what are you looking for...        https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/

Comment: Thank you, but this solution won't work with manual job abortion. I just want to synchronize regardless of conditions: kill the job -> kill the container

Comment: And the most fun part that it is default behaviour and works fine with everything except the case with docker

Comment: If you are afraid of existing running containers you can also make a cleanup stage before start the things you want to do ( I know is a workaround)
 And you can even program a job during the nights to clean up also these containers.

Comment: Yeah I know it, it's possible to find a workaround, but I just want to know why the default behaviour  isn't working here. It works with scripts or something similar, but not with docker containers

Comment: After working during several months with pipelines I only find out that it still "beta" in finding good docu... I am waiting for the Brent Laster book (Jenkins 2: up and running) and I hope it can solve our doubts. Then... good luck with the workaround!